# How to make a sed command to trim whitespace from the end of a string or normalize whitespace in the string?

Tags: sed

I have some data like the following

```
"brand": "Some brand name  ", "otherbrand": "Something else ", 

"brand":"Some  third way"
```

although a little bit more unstructured like that, however one structure that is the same is that there are recurring instances of "brand": around, with the following value having inconvenient whitespace.

What I need to do is to normalize whitespace, and to trim it in the value so that

```
"brand": "Some brand name  "
```

gets turned in to

```
"brand": "Some brand name"
```

and

```
"brand":"Some  third way"
```

gets turned in to

```
"brand":"Some third way"
```

the size of the file is

I would like to know how to do this with Sed, because I think I am going to have to do this kind of minor fixing in the data here and there, and I would like a way to do it ad hoc with just a line in the terminal.

Comment: Is this specific to the "brand" value?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed 's/ *"/"/g;s/  */ /g'
```

The first part removes any spaces that are trailing within quotes, and the second cuts down any multiple spaces to a single space:

```
 $ echo "Before:"; cat $TEMP/test.txt; echo "After:";sed 's/ *"/"/g;s/  */ /g' $TEMP/test.txt
Before:
"brand": "Some brand name  ", "otherbrand": "Something else ",
"brand":"Some  third way"
After:
"brand":"Some brand name","otherbrand":"Something else",
"brand":"Some third way"
```

Comment: is it just my test, or does this result in an extra space after "some brand name " and the following comma?  i get:  'brand: Some brand name , otherbrand: Something else'

Comment: @Daniel i've added example output, I think it's ok

Comment: it does look correct -- mine gives an extra space.  version of sed is 4.2.1

Comment: @Daniel: I'm using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':in
s/^\(\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*"[^"]*\) \{2,\}/\1 /
t in
:edge
s/^\(\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*"[^"]*\) \{1,\}"/\1"/
s/^\(\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*"\) \{1,\}/\1/
t edge
' YourFile
```

- POSIX version so `--posix -e` for gnu sed
- recursive remove multi space inside quote string (don't touch between, could be done with few modification)
- recursive remove edge space inside quoted string (one for begin and one for ending)